# Can i use an Apple built-in AU in my app?

Tags: macos, audio, operating-system

I´am dealing with a mini dsp. Now, i wan`t to add some hp/lp filter by loading the graphic eq audio unit from apple in a custom wrapper. The question is if there is no problem with distribution on Mac App Store. 
I am talking about AUGraphicEQ, AUDelay, etc...
Many thanks, 
Nahuel.

Comment: Note that a graphic EQ is not the correct way to do lp/hp. I am pretty sure there are AUs for lp and hp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any audio unit that's available on the system, including the Apple provided ones. Take a look at the [Audio Unit Hosting Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitHostingGuide_iOS/AudioUnitHostingFundamentals/AudioUnitHostingFundamentals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009492-CH3-SW11), specifically the [Identifier Keys for Audio Units](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitHostingGuide_iOS/UsingSpecificAudioUnits/UsingSpecificAudioUnits.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009492-CH17-SW14). No problems for Mac App Store distribution.